# randomForest model doesn't run

Tags: r, model, prediction

I try to run a `randomForest` model on `iris` data without the variable `Petal.Length`. The code give me errors on prédiction. How can I code properly? Thanks for help.
Richard

```
data (iris)
attach (iris)
iris$id <- 1:nrow(iris)

library (dplyr)
train <- iris %>% 
  sample_frac (0.8)
test <- iris %>% 
  anti_join(train, by = "id")

library (randomForest)
library (caret)

fit <- randomForest(Species ~ 
                      Sepal.Length +Sepal.Width +Petal.Width, data = train,)


prediction <- predict (fit, test [1:2 , 4])

confusionMatrix (test$Species,prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subsetting for test dataset is wrong. Just use

```
prediction <- predict (fit, newdata = test)
```

in place of

```
predict (fit, test [1:2 , 4])
```

It will automatically take the required independent variables.
Or you can use like

```
prediction <- predict (fit, subset(test, select = -c(Petal.Length)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `prediction` function, you have to supply all the numeric data used for training. Try this instead

`prediction <- predict (fit, test[ , c(1:4)])`